# Blade, не выводится секция из yield

Tags: laravel, blade

Есть такая структура:
**Controller:**

```
...
return view('index')
```

**views.layouts.main.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
</head>
<body>
@yield('widgets.header')
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**views.index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
content
@endsection
```

**views.widgets.header.blade.php**

```
@section('header')
header
@endsection
```

почему выводится только `content`, а `header` не выводится?
что не так в подключении `header.blade.php` из папки `widgets` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В индексе:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('header')
    header
@endsection

@section('content')
    content
@endsection
```

Вы должны указать `header` секцию в шаблоне в котором вы наследуете базовый, на данный момент у вас файл хедера нигде не подключен.
Если хотите иметь хедер в отдельном файле то используйте инструкцию `@include`

Comment: `@yield('header')` всё-равно не выводит header

Comment: @word перечитав ваш код, я полностью переписал свой ответ